# Unable to use Xamarin.Forms WebView for Dropbox authentication

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin.forms, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've run into a problem using WebView to access the authorization uri necessary to authorize access by my Xamarin forms (running under iOS) app. I don't believe the problem lies with the WebView and the particular url, and not the Dropbox API itself.

First, I should mention that I am able to use WebView to access arbitrary web sites, so I know I am able to access the web generally from within my app.

In the code below you will see that I have two buttons set up. The first uses a WebView to successfully access the Wikipedia page for Xamarin. The second attempts to contact Dropbox in order to begin the authentication process. However, that request fails with the message:

> Error (400)  It seems the app you were using submitted a bad request. If you would like to report this error to the app's developer, include the information below. Invalid redirect_uri. Must be an absolute uri.

Initially, I thought that the problem was that the redirection uri wasn't registered correctly, but if I copy the url being passed to the webview (included below as a comment), and paste it directly into safari, the authentication page opens as expected. It is only when using WebView that I receive the error message. That makes me think that it's not the redirect_uri, or the url itself, but something in the way that the WebView is presenting it to dropbox.com.

Can anyone help me out? I've also tried taking a uri that works in Safari / Chrome and passing it directly to the webview (bypassing DropboxOAuth2Helper) without any luck. The uri will work in Safari, but not in the WebView.

```
public App()
{
    Button xamarinBtn = new Button();
    xamarinBtn.Text = "Xamarin";
    xamarinBtn.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;
    xamarinBtn.StyleId = "Xamarin";

    Button dropboxBtn = new Button();
    dropboxBtn.Text = "Dropbox";
    dropboxBtn.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;
    dropboxBtn.StyleId = "Dropbox";

    StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
    layout.Children.Add(xamarinBtn);
    layout.Children.Add(dropboxBtn);

    ContentPage page = new ContentPage();
    page.Content = layout;

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(page);
}

private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    UrlWebViewSource source = new UrlWebViewSource();
    if (btn.StyleId == "Xamarin")
    {
            source.Url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin";
    }
    else if (btn.StyleId == "Dropbox")
    {
        string oauth2State = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        Uri authorizeUri = DropboxOAuth2Helper.GetAuthorizeUri(OAuthResponseType.Token, "d1612up7la63slo", "http://127.0.0.1:52475/authorize", oauth2State);
        source.Url = authorizeUri.AbsoluteUri; // https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=d1612up7la63slo&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A52475%2Fauthorize&state=1062a614aa3d4e2e85cd84de32903987
    }

    WebView webView = new WebView();
    webView.Source = source;

    ContentPage page = new ContentPage();
    page.Content = webView;

    MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to exclude Google Accounts from login to Dropbox, you have to switch to an external browser anyway, to do the authentication. Using the WebView is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) by Google and probably by others in future. This makes things a lot more complicated for developers, but in the end a bit more safe for users.

Answer (score 0):

You should add that as a OAuth 2 redirect URI for your app via the App Console:
[image]
After doing this, I tried OC code it works properly and can show the authorize view. But Unfortunately, the Dropbox for Xamarin failed. You can try to use another api to show this view:

```
Uri authorizeUri = DropboxOAuth2Helper.GetAuthorizeUri("d1612up7la63slo");
source.Url = source.Url = authorizeUri.AbsoluteUri;
```